# Why can't I place a div over a SVG using z-index

Tags: css, z-index, d3.js

I have the [following plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LCZJX4btqaYoj5es2D3Y) and as you can see (I default it to open) the SVG objects are placed over the HTML ones. This is despite having a z-index of -1 (I also tried 100).

```
// Navbar Component
:host.opened{
  height: 136px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
// SVG Component
this.svg = d3.select(this.elementRef.nativeElement)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1200)
  .attr("height", 400)
  .style("z-index", -1)
```

How could I got about forcing this HTML layer over the SVG one

Answer (score 2):

Svg doesn't uses z-index

Set the z-index on the DOM parent

```
[_nghost-qtc-0] jg-sankey {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from just using :host?

Comment: In your example, you aren't setting any z-index on jg-sankey... You are setting an z-index on the .opened class, but this one is applied to jg-navbar.